# line breaks (enter pressed) inside tags?

Tags: jquery

I have a div editablecontent, which has the following code

```
<span id="id1">Hello </span>
<span id="id2">there </span>
<span id="id3">how </span>
<span id="id4">are </span>
<span id="id5">you? </span>
```

Now the thing is when cursor is inside one of these spans and I press enter, I want it to be

```
<span id="id1">Hel[enter pressed here]</span>
<span id="xx">lo </span>
<span id="id2">there </span>
<span id="id3">how </span>
<span id="id4">are </span>
<span id="id5">you? </span>
```

so it detects if you're in a span an splits the span into a new one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use window.getSelection

tyr this 
http://jsfiddle.net/XRW4E/2/

Compleate Solution : 
http://jsfiddle.net/XRW4E/5/

Comment: this returns 


<span id="id3">how  [enter pressed here] <span id="xx"></span></span> so it does not break the "edited" span in the right way?

Comment: ok so you can now capture the tag inserted and get it out of parent by jquary ;)

Comment: yes you can use the id of just created node to capture parent and insert after that parent

Comment: I may be too stupid to do this :( is it not simply easier to insert a `</span><span id="">` at the cursors position???

Comment: cool, many thanks Champ! I've been struggling with this problem for two weeks :-(

Comment: @Mads Christian Sidenius: if you got your answer please upvote this answer and selected the answer as best answer.

Comment: the cursor resets after enter is pressed and is now at the beginning of the word of the span which the cursor was in to begin with? Pressing enter twice does not work?

Comment: In my eager to try out your example I forgot to say thanks. I'm so happy that you could help me out here! :-)